# How would I go about using regression to estimate a change in direction or movement in n-space?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression, vector-fields

I have a dependent variable which is a position in n-space (so a vector of length n). I want to use regression (or some other method if you have a suggestion) to determine whether independent variables can predict a significant change in direction (or just a significant movement in n-space). How can I go about doing this? Just multivariate multiple regression?

To clarify: the distributions are topics over documents, aggregated by author. So each observation is the mean vector for an author in a given year. All time intervals are the same. A 'movement' in n-space would just be a change of this mean vector. I would define a 'change in direction' as a change in the directional derivative, but I'm not sure I could achieve measuring that through regression. It would be fine if it was either the cumulative effect over a long period or sudden changes between two successive observations.

To provide an example, let's say I observe some intervention T on a subset of authors after a particular time threshold. Ignoring issues of causal inference, I might want to say that T is associated with a change in direction in n-space, holding other things constant (e.g. author traits).

Comment: Presumably your observations are given in a temporal sequence. But are all the time intervals the same? What exactly would constitute a "change in direction" or "movement"?  Must it be a reversal of direction or just a slight acceleration? Could it be the cumulative effect of small accelerations over a long period or are you looking only for sudden changes occurring between two successive times?

Comment: I've added information in response to your questions above, @whuber. Thanks!

Comment: That is helpful; thank you.  It still leaves us with a vague problem description. For instance, it's trivial to detect changes as you have defined them: when the mean vector in one year is not identical to the mean in the previous year, a change has occurred. Your use of statistical terminology, though, suggests you have in mind some kind of probability model and some form of hypothesis test--you may be looking for *significant* changes. Further clarification of these points would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I gave an example problem in the text above. I'm particularly looking for associations between independent variables (e.g. interventions, author traits, group traits, and changes thereof) and changes in position in n-space.